# Prepend a DIV already hidden so I can animate a slide in

Tags: jquery

I use an ajax call to retrieve a div that I want to prepend to my results DIV.  I don't want to add the style display:none to the div before it is returned because I use the same code elsewhere and don't want that style attached.

That being said how do I prepend an element to a div already hidden so I could use the fadeIn or slideIn function.

Here is what I have so far:

$('#results').prepend(singleresult);

singleresult contains a div with the result.

How do I make singleresult hidden before I prepend it so I can use a fancy automation function to get it to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a class to this div and do this css `.myPrependDiv {display:none;}` or just use `.ajaxDivHolder div{display:none}` after that the jquery fadein or slidein function will overwrite it.

Comment: ok so something like this:

$('#results').prepend(ajaxDivHolder); // CSS has this hidden

$(.ajaxDivHolder).html(singleresult).slideDown("slow");

That sounds good, let me try that.